# What folders should I backup to my computer

Tags: backup, rsync

I have a SGS2 with ICS. The phone is rooted. I use Titanium Backup Pro for backup, but that only backups to the phone itself, so if the phone is stolen or lost those backups are gone as well.

I have SSHDroid installed, and yesterday I made a backup of the sdcard folder to my home server using rsync. Now I would like to know if there are other folders that have data in them that I miss. I don't necessarily need a full backup of the phone, don't know if that's useful. I just want all user data safe.

So is there something that I'm missing? If so, what folders should I backup as well?

Comment: There's a number of mounts which differs form device to device. The read-only mounts (most importantly /system which contains the firmware) don't need a backup. The tmpfs file systems (/dev) also don't need one. App related userdata is in /data, personal/media files, etc. reside in the SD card partition, starting with Android 4.0 also in /data/media (the usual sdcard folder is just an export for seamless legacy support). In Samsung phones there might also be an /efs mount which holds the keys for encrypted partitions and mac/imei IDs iirc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SD card contains pretty much all the data you need.

In addition to app backup, you can also use SMS Backup+ to backup your texts to the SD card (and then to the home server).

Titanium Backup Pro version has an option to backup files to your Dropbox folder, so you can use that instead of rsync if you like.

Also, try to move as much data to the cloud as you can - including contacts, settings, photos etc - you get peace of mind knowing that most things are already backed up even if your phone gets damaged or stolen.

Comment: Thanks. I believe Titanium Pro makes a backup of sms, so that should be covered. I use crashplan on my computers for local backup and to the cloud.

Comment: As Sumesh suggested, synching the complete SD card should be sufficient (*Titanium Backup* stores its backup data there as well). You could use [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite) for this, regardless of the backup target (your computer or the cloud). Not everybody loves to have private data in the cloud (I don't, for example) -- but with *FolderSync*, everbody has the choice where to backup to.

Comment: Titanium will also backup your call log and wi-fi settings. I include both in my backups.

Comment: True, but it might create problems when trying to move between ROMs, so I usually avoid it. Works well if you're reinstalling the same/similar firmware, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you paid for the Pro version of Titanium Backup, you should have the option to store the backups to several online storage locations. Google Drive, Dropbox, and Box are built-in to Titanium Backup Pro. All you need to do is add your account info, then tell your schedule to back up to those locations.

This is how my phone is set up. If I lost my phone, I would be able to restore my app settings and call logs/text messages on a new phone through Titanium Backup. And since I tell Google Plus to automatically upload photos taken by my camera, I would have photos as well. Everything else that matters is already synced with google.